# Which file format is available on Apache Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm new to Apache Pig.

I'm not sure which input file format is available on Pig.

For example, Parquet, Text, Avro, RCFile and SequenceFile are available on Impala. (See: [How Impala Works with Hadoop File Formats](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_file_formats.html))

I guess text file is okay because data loading example is using `.log` file. (See: [Getting Started](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/start.html#data-load))
Also I found [AvroStorage page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/AvroStorage), so Avro is available.

And then, how about Parquet, RCFile, SequenceFile and more? Or, am I something wrong?

Please advise me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [built-in functions](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#load-store-functions) of the [1.4 version](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/), you can read the following :

1. BinStorage
2. JsonLoader, JsonStorage
3. PigDump
4. PigStorage
5. TextLoader
6. HBaseStorage
7. AvroStorage
8. TrevniStorage
9. AccumuloStorage
10. OrcStorage

With gzip and bzip [compression support](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#handling-compression) for some loaders.

You can use [HCatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+UsingHCat) to read data from any other Hadoop component.

And many other loaders in the [piggybank](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/) library.

Else, you can write your own [loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html#load-store-functions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's so many. That's why Pig is said "Pigs Eat Anything". https://pig.apache.org/philosophy.html#Pigs+Eat+Anything